# Azure Data Factory - "Invalid format" error

Tags: escaping, azure-data-factory

I have a 1-step pipeline in ADF which is a single "Web activity" which sends a `GET` request to a simple REST API. The complete definition is as follows:

`URL` : `https://allstate.myabsorb.com/api/rest/v1/ecommerce/transactions?transactiondate=2021-01-11`

`Method` : `GET`

**Headers**

`Authorization` : `xyz/123+abc123==`

`Content-Type` : `application/json`

When I execute this request via Postman, the request is successful. However, when I send the same request via Web Activity in Azure Data Factory, I receive the following error message:

```
Error calling the endpoint 'https://allstate.myabsorb.com/api/rest/v1/ecommerce/transactions?transactiondate=2021-01-11'. Response status code: ''. More details:Exception message: 'The format of value 'xyz/123+abc123==' is invalid.'. No response from the endpoint. Possible causes: network connectivity, DNS failure, server certificate validation or timeout.
```

Through testing I've discovered that if I remove both the equal sign ( = ) and the forward slash ( / ) from the Authorization string, I do receive a valid response from the API:

```
{"Message":"Authorization has been denied for this request."}
```

This is great. **This is the expected response I'm looking for** (note that ADF still considers this an error, but this is the desired output) The problem is that in practice **I cannot remove these characters from the string** because then the token is invalid which means I cannot gain access to the API... I need a way to modify the Authorization string to the correct "type" without changing the value.

Is there a way to allow special characters in my Authorization string for this REST API call?

---

This is what the result ***should*** look like:
[image]

---

This is what the successful result looks like in Postman

[image]

Comment: What's your Authorization type? Could you show the screenshot of the sample request in the postman and the web activity?

Comment: Authentication type is set to "None"

Answer (score 2):

To solve the issue, just add `Basic`  in front of `xyz/123+abc123==`, the header should be:

`Authorization` : `Basic xyz/123+abc123==`

Note there is a **space** between `Basic` and `xyz/123+abc123==`, then it will work fine.

[image]

Comment: This works at first glance, but adding "Basic " in front of the Authorization value still invalidates the Authorization Token.... In other words, when I use "Basic <valid auth key>", my access request is still denied....     

I'm sure you knew this already, but "xyz/123+abc123==" is just an example of a Authorization Token that matches the correct format, but is not actually valid...I can't provide a valid one for obvious reasons.

Comment: @aGuy Is your token a jwt(json web token)? If so, try to use `Bearer` instead of `Basic`.

Comment: Didn't work. Using 'Bearer <valid token>' in Postman still returns access denied message because the token becomes invalid with the additional text.

Answer (score 0):

After tryng to create a call a make like this

[image]

So try to do with authorization token

the answer that I get was

```
{"validations":{},"code":500.0,"message":"An unexpected error occurred.","term":"ErrorGeneric","_meta":{"status":500}}
```

Comment: In this case i used BEARER <Token> and make this work